# Proving that sweeping a triangle around different edges produces different volumes

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

Imagine there is a rectangle with side lengths $P$ and $Q$. If I take that rectangle and sweep it on its edge $P$ it will produce a cylinder of height $P$ and radius $Q$.

Now take that rectangle and split it at the diagonal to make two right-angle triangles. Since both triangles are the same in every way. I can spin both of them at the edge where the length is the same as the length of the original rectangle I will end up with two cones of height $P$ and those cones will also have the radius $Q$. This erroneously proves that the volume of a cylinder is twice that of cones of same radius and height. Which is obviously wrong and in fact the cylinder volume is three times the volume of such cone.

The only mistake I can find is that only one triangle will make the correct cone the other triangle will be spun on a corner. which means it will make sort of $(cylinder - cone)$ shape. and that part will be 2 times the volume of the correct cone.

Now I am struggling to prove that sweeping a triangle around different edges or corners produces different volumes.

Comment: The fact they haven't the same volume isn't surprising... Consider the **Pappus-Guldinus theorem** connecting those volumes with the position of the center of gravity of the revolving shapes (here triangles).

Comment: I tried looking up the proof for Pappus-Guldinus theorem and it involves triple integrals. So I gave up and just accepted it. While doing all this I found this quote from Pappus on Wikipedia " I am ashamed; I for one have proved things that are much more valuable and offer much application."  Wow just wow.

Comment: No, you don't need triple integrals ! See [here](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/james-gregory-and-the-pappus-guldin-theorem-introduction) for example.